# Laravel Eloquent Nested Relationships. Storing rows in controller variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have some working queries that are not ideal and I'd like to try perform them the Eloquent way to tidy it up.

I think I've got the relationships defined correctly but I can't figure out how to write the queries and store them in variables in the controller. I need to return these variables back to the view because I json encode them for use in JavaScript.

Here's what I have in my controller:

```html
public function show($idProject)
  {
    $project = ProjectsModel::with('user')->where('idProjects','=',$idProject)->first();
    $objsettings = ObjSettingsModel::where('idObjSettings','=',$project['ObjSettingsID1'])->first();
    $obj = ObjModel::where('idObjs','=',$objsettings['Objs_idObjs'])->first();

    return view('project')->with('project',$project)->with('obj',$obj)->with('objsettings',$objsettings);
  }
```

The naming conventions are a bit off so here's what this does.

I pass the $idProject to the controller from a link on my index page where I've looped through and paginated all rows from the Projects table.

The first query finds the project row where it's id (idProjects) matches the variable passed from the index page via the link (idProject). I've also successfully pulled the related user row from the user table using an eloquent relationship.

The next query pulls from an ObjSettings table which stores a number of settings values for an object which is shown on the page. I match the idObjSettings column of the ObjSettings table to the previously pulled $project['ObjSettingsID1'] which is essentially the foreign key in the projects table. There can be several ObjSettings for each Project.

The 3rd query pulls from the Obj table which stores details about an object. These are static details on objects such as name or size for example. I match the idObjs column to the previously pulled $objsettings['Objs_idObjs'] which is the foreign key in the ObjSettings table. One Obj can have many ObjSettings which are used in other Projects.

Here's how I'm passing the php variables to JS:

```html
<script>var obj = @json($obj);</script>
<script>var objsettings = @json($objsettings);</script>
```

Here are my relationships

ProjectsModel

```html
public function user()
  {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'Username', 'id');
  }


public function objsettings()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ObjSettingsModel', 'idObjSettings', 'ObjSettingsID1' );
  }
```

ObjSettingsModel

```html
public function objs()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\ObjsModel', 'Objs_idObjs', 'idObjs');
    }

public function projects()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\ProjectsModel', 'ObjSettingsID1', 'idObjSettings' );
    }
```

ObjModel

```html
public function objsettings()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\ObjSettingsModel', 'idObjs', 'Objs_idObjs');
    }
```

I've tried a whole range of queries such as:

```html
$project = ProjectsModel::with('user')->with('objsettings.objs')->where('idProjects','=',$idProject)->first();
$objsettings = $project->objsettings; 
$obj = $project->objsettings->objs;
```

but I keep running into issues such as "Property [objs] does not exist on this collection instance." I suppose I'm returning multiple rows in this case? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `loop` through `objsettings`

```
$project = ProjectsModel::with('user')->with('objsettings.objs')->where('idProjects','=',$idProject)->first();
$objsettings = $project->objsettings; 
foreach($objsettings as $objsetting){
     $objs = $objsetting->objs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this still generates the "Property [objs] does not exist on this collection instance." error.

Comment: Hang on, I was using objsettings instead of objsetting in the for loop. Let me retest...

Comment: I think your solution is working because I'm now stuck on the next step. I omitted a 4th query from my original post for simplicity.

How would I include this: 

$extras = ExtrasModel::where('Objs_idObjs','=',$objs['idObjs'])->get();


As it stands, I receive the error: Property [ExtraSetting01] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: this is unclear, may be you should edit your question with latest error or make a new question with new error and full data

Comment: I'll investigate a little more. I think it's now returning a collection instead of a single row so I may need to loop through this one also. I'll lodge a new question if I can't figure it out. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: i guess so too, try to debug your code, use `dd()` to see the output, you may find something useful

Comment: Just to follow up, I resolved this last piece by breaking out each row from the returned $objsettings into it's own variable since I know there will only ever be two. In the foreach loop you suggested I added $i++; and ${"objsettings" . $i} = $objsetting; This way I can simply pass objsettings1 and objsettings2 to my view and my JS. I'm not sure how you would go about this for a large number of rows however.